# How to specify redis client dependency for logback-redis-appender

Tags: gradle, redis, logback, jedis

How to specify latest redis client dependency for logback-redis-appender in gradle

```
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.cwbase/logback-redis-appender/1.1.5
```

I want to use 2.9.0 dependency of https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/redis.clients/jedis instead of 2.5.2 being used right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `build.gradle`:

```
compile group: 'redis.clients', name: 'jedis', version: '2.9.0'
```

or

```
dependencies {
    compile "redis.clients:jedis:2.9.0"
}
```